# Data extraction with Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, scraping

My goal is to be able to extract data from web pages such as address, product categories and their products on e-commerce sites.

Performing this operation on a regular expression basis is not possible on a large number of websites.

How could we do that with Tensorflow? Would you have an example in mind or the methodology to achieve this?

Comment: Are you familiar with web mining?

Comment: Yes I am. That's the reason why I do not want to use regular expressions. I will work quite well for addresses but not for product pages for example. And I don't want to change the code for every update for every webpage I will visit.